# How to sum specific values from two different txt files in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 txt files with names and scores. For example:

```
File 1          File 2           Desired Output
Name     Score  Name     Score   Name     Score
Michael  20     Michael  30      Michael  50
Adrian   40     Adrian   50      Adrian   90
Jane     60                      Jane     60
```

I want to sum scores with same names and print them. I tried to pair names and scores in two different dictionaries and after that merge the dictionaries. However, I can't keep same names with different scores. So, I'm stuck here. I've written something like following :

```
d1=dict()
d2=dict()
with open('data1.txt', "r") as f:
    test = [i for line in f for i in line.split()]
    i = 0
    while i < len(test) - 1:
        d1[test[i]] = test[i + 1]
        i += 2
    del d1['Name']

with open('data2.txt', "r") as f:
    test = [i for line in f for i in line.split()]
    i = 0
    while i < len(test) - 1:
        d2[test[i]] = test[i + 1]
        i += 2
    del d2['Name']
z = dict(d2.items() | d1.items())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dictionary comprehension should get you what you are after. I have assumed the contents of the files are:

**File1.txt:**

```
Name     Score
Michael  20
Adrian   40
Jane     60
```

**File2.txt:**

```
Name     Score
Michael  30
Adrian   50
```

Then you can get a total as:

```py
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file_in:
    next(file_in) # skip header
    file1_data = dict(row.split() for row in file_in if row)

with open("file2.txt", "r") as file_in:
    next(file_in) # skip header
    file2_data = dict(row.split() for row in file_in if row)

result = {
    key: int(file1_data.get(key, 0)) + int(file2_data.get(key, 0))
    for key
    in set(file1_data).union(file2_data) # could also use file1_data.keys()
}

print(result)
```

This should give you a result like:

```
{'Michael': 50, 'Jane': 60, 'Adrian': 90}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict


name_scores = defaultdict(int)
files = ('data1.txt', 'data2.txt')
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for name, score in f.split():
            name_scores[name] += int(score)
```

edit: You'll probably have to skip any header line and maybe clean up trailing white spaces, but the gist of it is above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But now, I'm getting AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: add in a `next(f)` and switch your innermost `for` to : `for name, score in [r.split() for r in f]`